# Android Studio APK Analyzer fails to load mapping.txt

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-proguard

I have started obfuscating an Android app, which contains a number of 3rd party libraries. After setting a first basing config that allowed me to obfuscate a debug build using R8, I have opened the APK in the APK Analyzer to inspect the obfuscation, which was in place. After this I clicked `Load Proguard mappings...` and selected the `mapping.txt` from the obfuscation run. The classes are not de-obfuscated and AS reports:

```
   APK Analyzer successfully loaded maps from: 
   There were problems loading: mapping.txt
```

AGP Plugin 3.3.2 + `android.enableR8=true`

Why is this happening? I can't find a bug report about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that Android Studio 3.3.x doesn't like the starting comments of the `mapping.txt`. It's important to remove them before opening :

```
# compiler: R8
# compiler_version: 1.4.57
# min_api: 21
```

This is fixed in Android Studio 3.4.